# How to skip the beginning of a message with Grok Patterns?

Tags: regex, linux, filebeat, grok

I am trying to extract only the last part of a Linux log using Grok Patterns in Graylog, but it's harder than I tought.

Here's the message that I receive:

*Mar 18 11:10:01 graylog CRON[14637]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root*

I only want to keep date, time and the "session closed for user root" part.

This is what I tried, without results:

```
%{GREEDYDATA} pam_unix(cron:session):
%{GREEDYDATA} session closed for user root
%{MONTH} %{BASE10NUM} %{TIME} %{GREEDYDATA}graylog CRON[18698]: pam_unix(cron:session):
```

Maybe I am still using "greedydata" wrong(?), any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
%{MONTH:month} %{BASE10NUM:day} %{TIME:time} %{DATA}: pam_unix\(cron:session\):\s*%{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

*Details*:

- `%{MONTH:month}` - month name
- `%{BASE10NUM:day}` - one or more digits
- `%{TIME:time}` - time pattern
- `%{DATA}` - `.*?` lazy-dot regex pattern, matches any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as *few* as possible (**note** that you may change it to `%{DATA:cron}` to get `graylog CRON[14637]` in the output)
- `: pam_unix\(cron:session\):` - a literal `: pam_unix(cron:session):` text
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `%{GREEDYDATA:message}` - `.*` regex pattern matching the rest of the line.